# connectedCallback not firing when state is used in NavigationMixin

Tags: navigationmixin.navigate, connected-callback

connectedCallback lifecycle event is not firing when state is used during navigation.

If state is removed than connectedCallback is firing.

This behavior seems strange to me.

AM I missing some information on connectedCallbacks.

I would have been OK if it wasn't or was firing in both the cases

Not firing when using this method :

```
navigateToTabWithParameters(tabName, parameters) {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__navItemPage',
        attributes: {
            apiName: tabName
        },
        state: parameters
    });
}
```

Firing when using this

```
    navigateToTab(tabName) {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__navItemPage',
        attributes: {
            apiName: tabName
        }
    });
}
```